# FPDF - Line break inside cell with text from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm trying to generating a PDF-file with data from SQL with PHP using FPDF. But when I'm trying to make a line breaks with `"\n"` in the text from the SQL, that just show the text `"\n"` in the output. If I write the text directly in the MultiCell it make the correct line break.

Below is a copy of my file:

```
$f_data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter = 1")
or die (mysql_error());
$d_data = mysql_fetch_array($f_data);

$pdf=new FPDF(L);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',11);
$pdf->MultiCell (80, 8, $d_data[my_data], 1, 0, 'L',1); //This shows the string "This \n is \n a \n test" without making the breaks
$pdf->MultiCell (80, 8, "This \n is \n a \n test", 1, 0, 'L',1); //This shows correctly with line breaks
$pdf->Output();
```

Output of first MultiCell:

> "This \n is \n a \n test" -> Wrong

Output of the second MultiCell:

> "This
>   is
>   a
>   test" -> Correct

I hope someone can help me with a solution, which make the `"\n"` text from `$d_data[my_data]` to force a line break.

Thanks.

Comment: What does output `die(nl2br($d_data['my_data']));` (before the FPDF creation) ? Is the DB data stored correctly (with line breaks) ?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.
The text directly from the DB is "This \n is \n a \n test". The format is UTF8.

Comment: is the text saved with line breaks or are the `\n` saved plain text ?

Comment: It help to remove the \n tags and just make a normal "Shift" + "enter" brake directly in the DB.

Comment: Always keep it simple I think:-)
If you want the point, please leave an answer.
Thanks.